# Problem with importing CSV files (phpmyadmin)

Tags: database, csv, import, phpmyadmin, shopware

I am trying to import a CSV file to my shopware database on PHPMyAdmin.

But I get the following Error: Invalid number of columns in CSV import in row 1.

Although the number of columns should be correct.

It is separated by tabs.

```
    1c16604c-c821-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003    c9e4cc05-20ab-4222-8c76-dca1877934ef    1   NULL     0xb7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca     NULL    19.7483 0.1000  0.9999  " ""2020-07-17  08:03:17.066"" "    NULL
1c16604c-c821-11ea-87d0-0242ac130004    c9e4cc05-20ab-4222-8c76-dca1877934ef    1   NULL     0xb7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca     NULL    22.2162 1.0000  1.4999  " ""2020-07-17  08:03:17.066"" "    NULL
```

these are my settings for the import:

Fields terminated by:
\t

Fields enclosed by:
"

Fields escaped by:
\

Lines terminated by:
auto

thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Lines terminated by: auto" whats is the meaning of auto? \n or \r or both?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `Fields enclosed by "` which isn't the case for the fields in the sample that you've posted. Also, check the datetime column and how it's enclosed.